# validation on signup if the user already exists in the database using react redux express

Tags: reactjs, express, validation, redux, react-redux

So, as the title suggests, I am trying to find if the user exists or not. Here's what I have done until now. I'm having trouble with handling validation in the `handleSubmit` function.

**RegistrationForm.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { registerUser, checkValidUser } from "../actions/userActions"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import validator from "validator"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"

class RegistrationForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      username: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
    }
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target
    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    })
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const { username, email, password } = this.state

    const registrationData = this.state

    if (!username || !email || !password) {
      return toastError("Credentials should not be empty")
    }

    if (username.length < 6) {
      return toastError("Username should be greater than 6 characters.")
    }

    if (!validator.isEmail(email)) {
      return toastError("Invalid email.")
    }

    if (password.length < 6) {
      return toastError("Password must contain 6 characters.")
    }

    this.props.dispatch(checkValidUser(email)) // how do i properly handle validations here

    this.props.dispatch(
      registerUser(registrationData, () => this.props.history.push("/login"))
    )
  }

  render() {
    const isRegistrationInProgress = this.props.registration.isRegistrationInProgress
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="field">
          <p className="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
            <input
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              name="username"
              value={this.state.username}
              className="input"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Username"
            />
            <span className="icon is-small is-left">
              <i className="fas fa-user"></i>
            </span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="field">
          <p className="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
            <input
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              name="email"
              value={this.state.email}
              className="input"
              type="email"
              placeholder="Email"
            />
            <span className="icon is-small is-left">
              <i className="fas fa-envelope"></i>
            </span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="field">
          <p className="control has-icons-left">
            <input
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              name="password"
              value={this.state.password}
              className="input"
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
            />
            <span className="icon is-small is-left">
              <i className="fas fa-lock"></i>
            </span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="field">
          <div className="control">
            {isRegistrationInProgress ? (
              <button className="button is-success is-loading">Sign Up</button>
            ) : (
              <button onClick={this.handleSubmit} className="button is-success">
                Sign up
              </button>
            )}
            <Link to="/login">
              <p className="has-text-danger">
                Already have an account? Sign In
              </p>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return state
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RegistrationForm)
```

**checkValidUser action creator**

```js
export const checkValidUser = (email) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: "CHECK_VALID_USER_STARTS" })
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/users/checkValidUser/${email}`)
      dispatch({
        type: "CHECK_VALID_USER_SUCCESS",
        data: { message: res.data.message } 
      })
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: "CHECK_VALID_USER_ERROR",
        data: { error: "Something went wrong" },
      })
    }
  }
}
```

**route**- `router.get("/checkValidUser/:email", usersController.checkValidUser)`

**checkValidUser controller function**

```js
  checkValidUser: async (req, res, next) => {
    const { email } = req.params
    try {
      const user = await User.findOne({ email })
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(404).json({ error: "No user found" })
      }
      return res.status(200).json({ message: "User already exists" })
    } catch (error) {
      return next(error)
    }
  }
```

**registration reducer**

```js
const initialState = {
  isRegistrationInProgress: false,
  isRegistered: false,
  registrationError: null,
  user: {},
  message: "",
}

const registration = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "REGISTRATION_STARTS":
      return {
        ...state,
        isRegistrationInProgress: true,
        registrationError: null,
      }

    case "REGISTRATION_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...state,
        isRegistrationInProgress: false,
        registrationError: null,
        isRegistered: true,
        user: action.data,
      }

    case "REGISTRATION_ERROR":
      return {
        ...state,
        isRegistrationInProgress: false,
        registrationError: action.data.error,
        isRegistered: false,
        user: {},
      }
    case "CHECK_VALID_USER_STARTS":
      return {
        ...state,
        isRegistrationInProgress: true,
      }
    case "CHECK_VALID_USER_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...state,
        isRegistrationInProgress: false,
        message: action.data.message,
      }
    case "CHECK_VALID_USER_ERROR":
      return {
        ...state,
        registrationError: action.data.error,
      }

    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default registration
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't `checkValidUser` the same type of validation like `password.length < 6`? I would just call it synchronously inside the validation. On the backend side I would change the status codes if possible. If the user already exists, it's the problematic case, so 419 (conflict) is a better fit than 200. 200 or 204 instead should be returned if the email wasn't used. With this the frontend check is quite easy:

```js
export const checkValidUser = async (email) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/users/checkValidUser/${email}`)
      return true
    } catch (err) {
      return false
    }
}
```

and in `handleSubmit`

```js
  handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const { username, email, password } = this.state

    const registrationData = this.state

...

    if(!(await checkValidUser(email))) {
      return toastError("...")
    }

    this.props.dispatch(
      registerUser(registrationData, () => this.props.history.push("/login"))
    )
  }
```

With this you don't need the `CHECK_VALID_USER`-states, but may want to add some kind of `VALIDATION_IN_PROGRESS` action to show some indicator on the page, that a background process is running, like a spinner. This can be achieved with a simple `try/finally` wrapper. So no matter in which case the validation will be exited the validation progress status will be reset.

```js
  handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const { username, email, password } = this.state

    const registrationData = this.state

    try {
       this.props.dispatch(setValidationProgress(true)
    ...

       if(!(await checkValidUser(email))) {
         return toastError("...")
       }
    } finally {
         this.props.dispatch(setValidationProgress(false)
    }

    this.props.dispatch(
      registerUser(registrationData, () => this.props.history.push("/login"))
    )
  }
```